# Transforming speechUtterance into a Wave form

Tags: audio, visualization, web-audio-api, speech-synthesis

I've been researching far and wide for a simple solution to animate the speech being played by Webkit's `speechUtterance` but it seems there is no library for that.

Now the question is, can I join the [visualization of audio](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Audio_API/Visualizations_with_Web_Audio_API) with that of [speech utterance](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/speechSynthesis)? All that I can currenty find is that the AudioContext requires some sort of datastream, which is not what Speech Utterance outputs.